# How to change factor to string in R

Tags: xml, r, dataframe

I am working with a data frame that is a list of sequences

```
Alpha_Helix = xmlParse("AlphaTbl.Xml")
all_seq = getNodeSet(Alpha_Helix, path = "//Protein/sequence", )
all_seq = xmlToDataFrame(all_seq)
```

I want to find the length of the sequences in each row and then carry out some other work with the sequences but am having trouble accessing them.

When I try:

```
length(all_seq$text[1])
[1] 1
nchar(all_seq$text)
Error in nchar(all_seq$text) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector
nchar(all_seq$text[1])
Error in nchar(all_seq$text[1]) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector


as.character(all_seq) # Works
[1] "c(117, 91, 8)"
```

How can I access the strings too?

Comment: Look at str(all_seq) and then add the option stringsAsFactors=FALSE to xmlToDataFrame (see ?data.frame for details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I Googled around and found something helpful.

```
require(stringi)
require(stringr)

str_length(all_seq$text)
[1]  249  274  261 
stri_length(all_seq$text)
[1]  249  274  261
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried wrapping your vector in `as.character`?

Comment: as.character(all_seq) # Gives me a count of the length , BUT how can I access the strings too.(?)

>"c(117, 91, 81)"